# Picasso - force fetch/load

Tags: android, caching, picasso

I need to cache all images from response (currectly I am using **OkHttpClient**, **OkHttpDownloader** and **Picasso** classes). And caching looks like it is working.

But all images in the response have timestamp where is last update time of that image. It is possible to force picasso to **re-fetch/re-load** image to cache if the timestamp will be outdated? But I dont want to invalidate whole cache - just that one image.

Comment: Try with `Picasso.with(Context).invalidate(file/Uri);`

Comment: But how I can get "file/Uri" ? For example model situation:open app -> REST call -> load image into cache -> show it -> close app -> open app -> REST call -> get image with timestamp - can I use image URL ?

Comment: Yes you can use the image url instead of file/uri. I haven't test it, but it should work.

Comment: I tested it and it doesnt work. I call invalidate on that URL but the picture is taken from device cache anyway.